# How to take apart a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, factoring

Suppose I have a polynomial: $x^3-8x^2+17x-4$. How do I know it will always be $(x-4)(x^2-4x+1)$ by solving it?

I'm struggling to figure out what to look for in the polynomial to give me a hint or clue of where to start to get the answer of $(x-4)(x^2-4x+1)$

Comment: I think you mean $(x-4)(x^2-4x+1)$ instead of $(x-4)(x-4x+1)=(x-4)(1-3x)$

Comment: Your second factor is not right. One can hope for a rational root, and then by the Rational Roots Theorem the only possibilities are $\pm 1, \pm 2,\pm 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this cubic factors over the rationals, by Gauss's lemma it factors over the integers, and it must factor as (linear)(quadratic), i.e. as $(x - r)(x^2 + a x + b)$ where $r,a,b$ are integers, and $r$ is a root of the polynomial.  Since $rb = 4$, there aren't too many possibilities to try for $r$ ...

Comment: how do you know rb = 4? where is the 4 coming from? from the (x - 4) factor?

Comment: @user983246: expanding $(x−r)(x^2+a\,x+b)=x^3+(a-r)x^2+(b-ar)x-rb$; inspecting the coefficients (the constant term in this case) of the original polynom gives $-rb=-4$

Comment: great explanation